# not able to use not exist keyword if subquery does not have join with query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to update [dbo].[ErrorLogs] **if key with value 'ABCDEF' does not exist in [dbo].[BatchEncryptedKeys]**.
But the problem is to use '**not exists**' keyword, i should have join with table [dbo].[ErrorLogs] [dbo].[BatchEncryptedKeys] on their common column.
but there is **no common column between them**.
can anyone suggest the alternate solution?

```
sample data

table ErrorLogs
[ID] [ProcessedOnDate] [ErrorMessage]           [ExternalID]
 1    2020-07-22       'Invalid CompanyID'       'EXT-001'
 2    2020-07-22       'Invalid CompanyName'     'EXT-002'

table BatchEncryptedKeys
[ID] [CompanyID]  [CompanyName]                [Key]
 1    34212       'Marines International'      'JABSCAIBCJS'
 2    23421       'TCS'                        'AJIDSBAIU'
```

what i want is, if key = 'ABCDEF' does not exist in  [dbo].[BatchEncryptedKeys]
table then i want to update the ErrorMessage column of [dbo].[ErrorLogs] table
with message "Invalid Key".

'ABCDEF' is a Encrypted Key provided by user as a input.
input can be anything.
i am just checking if that input exists in my table or not.
if not then that key is invalid.

```
update [dbo].[ErrorLogs]
set
   ProcessedOnDate = GETDATE(),
   ErrorMessage = Concat(ErrorMessage,' Key is Invalid. ')
where ID = 36
      and not exists (
                     select * from [dbo].[BatchEncryptedKeys]
                     where Key = 'ABCDEF'
);
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your code does what you describe you want.

Comment: You state **if key with value 'ABCDEF' exist in [dbo].[B]** yet in your SQL you're using `NOT EXISTS`. Which is it? Should records with ABCDEF only be included, or excluded?

Comment: Based on your problem description, I don't see why your query is "wrong". It accomplishes what you say it needs to. You don't "need" to do a JOIN of any kind.

Comment: You could simply use an IF statement if you simply want to do thing differently.

Comment: We'll need sample data from both tables to be of any assistance.

Comment: When you say "I should have join" - what makes you say this? Typically the query inside an EXISTS will coordinate with the query outside, but it doesn't have to.. EXISTS is a device that simply tests the truth of "and this subquery returns rows" - is it what you want? That so long as there isn't any key ABCDEF in B, you'll update a record in A with some info?

Comment: i have updated a sample data please refer that. thank you

Comment: FWIW ... Your SQL already accomplishes what you are asking for. Judging by the tables and data you provided however, I suspect there is a more fundamental problem.

I don't understand why you are trying to 'UPDATE' the error log instead of inserting a new value, unless you are simply trying to update the Error Date.

I normally don't second guess the OP, but looking for a hard coded ID value doesn't seem right, unless this is simply some Ad-Hoc query you will never run again.

Comment: @Jason i am updating the error message for specific ID. and 'not exist' keyword does not perform the check unless outer query and inner query have join on common column inside  'not exist' .  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15    please refer B point from this documentation.

Comment: That's just an example @goku0055 ... that's not the ONLY way it works. Not that the documentation says ...

EXISTS Returns TRUE if a subquery contains any rows.

That's all it does.

Comment: @Jason i have tried IF NOT EXISTS () also but ErrorMessage column is not getting updated.. not sure what the problem is, if Not Exists returns true. because i am not getting any exceptions

Comment: RUN 
select * from [dbo].[BatchEncryptedKeys] where Key = 'ABCDEF'

Verify that it returns no results.

RUN
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ErrorLogs] WHERE id = 36

Verify that you get 1 Result

As a last resort ... instead of using CONCAT try ...

ErrorMessage = ISNULL(ErrorMessage, ') +  ' Key is Invalid. '

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is running in a stored procedure that you're passing parameters into (and that I understand your need), try this:

```
DECLARE 
    @Key VARCHAR(50) = 'ABCDEF',
    @Id INT = 36;

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [dbo].[BatchEncryptedKeys] WHERE [Key] = @Key )
BEGIN

    UPDATE [dbo].[ErrorLogs]
    SET
        ProcessedOnDate = GETDATE(),
        ErrorMessage = CONCAT ( ISNULL ( ErrorMessage, '' ), ' Key is Invalid. ' )
    WHERE ID = @Id;

END
```

Comment: tried this before but double checked again. this does not update ErrorMessage Column. only shows command completed successfully. thank you.

Comment: What happens when you run ...

select * from [dbo].[BatchEncryptedKeys] where Key = 'ABCDEF'

Do you get a row back?

Comment: @Jason raises a valid question. Perhaps the key 'ABCDEF' **does** exist. Run his query to check.

Comment: One hint  - CONCAT does return null in case one of the argument is null. Solution with ISNULL then should work

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the Message is not updated ... try ...

```
update [dbo].[ErrorLogs] set
   ProcessedOnDate = GETDATE(),
   ErrorMessage = ISNULL(ErrorMessage, '') + ' Key is Invalid. '
where
   ID = 36
   and not exists (
      select * from [dbo].[BatchEncryptedKeys] where Key = 'ABCDEF'
   );
```